# Is there a way to maximize/minimize a custom function in R?

Tags: r, optimization

I'm trying to minimize a custom function. It should accept five parameters and the data set and do all sorts of calculations, producing a single number as an output. I want to find a combination of five input parameters which yields smallest output of my function.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I wrote a post [listing a few tutorials using `optim`](http://jeromyanglim.blogspot.com/2011/02/r-optimisation-tips-using-optim-and.html).

Here is a quote of the relevant section:

"The combination of the R function `optim` and a custom created objective
function, such as a minus log-likelihood function provides a powerful tool for
parameter estimation of custom models.

- [Scott Brown's tutorial](http://www.psych.unimelb.edu.au/AMPC2011/rt.zip) includes an example of
  this.
- [Ajay Shah has an example](http://www.mayin.org/ajayshah/KB/R/documents/mle/mle.html) 
  of writing a likelihood function and then getting a maximum likelihood
  estimate using `optim`.
- Benjamin Bolker has great material available on the web from his book
  [Ecological Models and Data in R](http://www.math.mcmaster.ca/~bolker/emdbook/index.html).
  PDFs, Rnw, and R code for early versions of the chapters are provided on
  the website.
  Chapter 6 ([likelihood and all that](http://www.math.mcmaster.ca/~bolker/emdbook/chap6A.pdf))
  , 7 ([the gory details of model fitting](http://www.math.mcmaster.ca/~bolker/emdbook/chap7A.pdf)),
  and 8 ([worked likelihood estimation examples](http://www.math.mcmaster.ca/~bolker/emdbook/chap8A.pdf)).
- Brian Ripley has a [set of slides on simulation and optimisation in R](http://portal.stats.ox.ac.uk/userdata/ruth/APTS2012/Rcourse5.pdf). 
  In particular it provides a useful discussion of the various optimisation
  algorithms available using `optim`".

Comment: Lately I've been playing with DEoptim as a nice "no start points necessary" optimizer.

Comment: A recent posting of John Myles White on the optim command in R may also be of [interest](http://www.johnmyleswhite.com/notebook/2011/06/18/speeding-up-mle-code-in-r/).

Comment: @Mike agreed; [DEoptim](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/DEoptim/index.html) gives more robust alternative (DE = Differential Evolution)

Answer (score 12):

In addition to Jeromy Anglim's answer, I have some more links.

Next to `optim` there is another function in base R that allows for what you want: `nlminb`. Check `?nlminb` and `?optim` for examples of the usage.

There are a bunch of packages that can do optimizations. What I found most interesting were the packages [optimx](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/optimx/) and, quite new, the [neldermead](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/neldermead/index.html) package for different versions of the simplex algorithm.

[Furthermore, you might want to have a look at the CRAN Task View on Optimization for more packages](http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/Optimization.html)

Please note that my recommendations all assume that you have a deterministic function (i.e., no random noise). For functions that are not strictly deterministic (or too big) you would need to use algorithms such as simulated annealing or genetic algorithms. But the [CRAN Task View](http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/Optimization.html) should have what you need.

Answer (score 1):

Is your function continuous and differentiable?  You might be able to use optim, either with user-supplied derivatives or numerically approximated ones.